# Tengo este api en python y mi search no funciona para traer las actividades economicas

Tags: python, sql, api, crud, odoo14

```
    def get_economic_activity(self):
    if self.vat:
        endpoint = 'https://api.hacienda.go.cr/fe/ae?identificacion=' + str(self.vat)
        status_code = False 
        try:
            response_fe = requests.get(endpoint, timeout=5)
            status_code = response_fe.status_code
            response_fe.raise_for_status()
            response_content = json.loads(response_fe.content)
            if response_content and response_content is not None:
                activities = response_content["actividades"]
                a_code = []
                for activity in activities:
                    if activity["estado"] == "A":
                        a_code.append(activity["codigo"])

                existing_activities = self.env['economic.activity'].search([('code', 'in', a_code)])

                if not existing_activities:
                    for activity in activities:
                        if activity["estado"] == "A":
                            self.env['economic.activity'].create({
                                'code': activity.get('codigo'),
                                'description': activity.get('descripcion')
                            })

        except requests.Timeout as rte:
            _logger.error("Request `response_fe` " + str(rte))
            alert = {
                'title': _('Warning'),
                'message': f'Estamos experimentando problemas con la conexión al Ministerio de Hacienda por '
                           f'favor intente nuevamente o póngase en contacto con el administrador del sistema.'
            }
            return {'value': {'vat': self.vat}, 'warning': alert}
        except Exception as err:
            _logger.error("Request `response_fe` " + str(err))
            if status_code != requests.codes.ok:
                alert = {
                    'title': _('Warning'),
                    'message': f'El número de identificación ingresado no fue encontrado como un '
                               f'contribuyente registrado ante el Ministerio de Hacienda de Costa Rica.'
                }
                return {'value': {'vat': self.vat}, 'warning': alert}
```

Tengo este código el cuál necesito que si la actividad economica no esta en la tabla economic.activity la cree y si ya esta creada solo la busque y la guarde en la variable wxisting_activities, pero la variable me queda toda en false y me las esta creando siempre aun existiendo ya, no se si hay algo mal en mi search...